# Angular 6 - How to stop infinite polling in subscribe()

Tags: html, angular, event-handling, parent-child, infinite-loop

So I want to show an icon based on whether or not the number of projects in my list is > 3. I am using this getProjects() function that I need to subscribe to in order to get the data. I am setting a boolean when I subscribe that checks the number of projects in the list, then in my HTML, I use a ngIf to show the icon based on the boolean. I am able to get it to show correctly, however, I think I am constantly polling in my subscribe, and setting this boolean over and over again because it is making my webpage run really slow.

I have already tried the take(1) method which doesnt seem to stop the subscription, as well as set it to a "this.variable" scope inside my component. I am currently using event emitters however that is not working either.

This is my code so far,

Function that I subscribe to (in a different component):

```
getProjects(): Observable<ProjectInterfaceWithId[]> {
    const organizationId = localStorage.getItem('organizationId');
    return this.firestoreService.collection('organizations').doc(organizationId)
      .collection('projects').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as ProjectInterface;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data} as ProjectInterfaceWithId;
        })),
        map(list => {
          if (list.length !== 0) {
            this.buildProjectLookup(list);
            this.projects = list;
            return list;
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

Function that i use to get the data and set the boolean:

```
@Input() toggle: boolean;
@Output() iconStatus = new EventEmitter();

displayIcon() {
    this.projectService.getProjects()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        list => {
          if(list.length >= 3){
              this.toggle = true;
              this.iconStatus.emit(this.toggle);
          }
        });
  }
```

HTML:

```
<i *ngIf="displayIcon()" class="material-icons">list</i>
```

Is there any way for me to literally just check the list length once so I don't get caught in this subscription loop? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it could be happening due to the ngIf referring to the `displayIcon()` method.

Every time change detection runs within your component, this method will be called. If your component is using default change detection, this will be very often.

see https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/ for more

One way this could be fixed is by making the ngIf refer to a variable instead.
For example, you could set a `projects$` observable using

```
this.projects$ = this.projectService.getProjects()
      .pipe(
         take(1),
         tap(projects => this.iconStatus.emit(projects.length >= 3))
      );
```

This observable should likely be instantiated in your `ngOnInit()` method.
Then in your template you can use

`<i *ngIf="(projects$ | async)?.length >= 3" class="material-icons">list</i>`

Comment: ohhhh okay awesome, that helped with the performance issue, which totally makes sense, you dont want to tie it to a method. However i am running into a bug where projects.length is always emitting 3, so the statement is always true... do you think thats a case of having it in the ngoninit, so its not updating my projects list when i change to a different component with different projects?

Comment: What dictates which projects should be loaded? Is it by a parameter in the route e.g. navigating from route company/google/projects to route company/facebook/projects should refetch projects? If so, you will want to subscribe to the params variable of ActivatedRoute and refetch projects in the subscription. Let me know if I misinterpreted what you mean

Comment: So i have organizations, and each organization has its own set of projects. and yes, so like the routing is like home/org-overview/org-dashboard, where each org has its own project list. Currently, the method i listed above is my only way of getting a list of projets. I am confused on what you mean by the subscribing to params variable and refetching, i am still new to rxjs programming haha

Comment: Regarding subscribing to params: if you inject an instance of ActivatedRoute into your components constructor, that instance has a property that is an observable (its called params). If you subscribe to this observable, you can define code in the subscription that will run each time one of the route parameters is changed. The other thing you can do is make a call to the backend using a switchMap operator on this params observable. I put together a little example here let me know if you have questions: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6n3nn4